Accuracy of continental drift maps?
I was looking up maps of continental drift through history and I noticed something that seemed off to me.  Madagascar seems like it very obviously must have separated from what is now southern Mozambique.

However, every single map of continental drift that I could find shows Madagascar and India nestled far north up against Kenya  
And just incase I have to remind anyone here how big Africa is, that's a discrepancy of 1,700 miles!
Are drift maps just highly inaccurate, or is Madagascar and the coast of Africa's shape just a coincidence?

"Very obvious" is wrong.
You have to look at more than just the rough shape of the land surface, first continetal crust often extends below the water line. Then you need to look at the seaflor which has the record of the actual movement.

Sources
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1464343X13001349
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0012825222001878
